# Updating feature file will not update the generated step definitions

Tags: definition, specflow, feature-file

I wrote a feature file using Specflow and generated step definitions. I went back to my feature file to update my scenarios but when I generate step definitions, it won't update the step definitions, instead it would overwrite what's already been generated. Is there any way to have it update the generated step definitions/code without losing what's been generated before?

Comment: Just copy to the clipboard, don't generate  the steps file again

Comment: Thanks. It seemed like that was the only way to prevent it from overwriting the whole code.